# Can't get Data from Repeater for Function

Tags: c#, asp.net

I wanna put data I got from `Repeater` ( container.DataItem ) to function as Parameter.
This is what I have tried:

```cs
protected String getLink(string CustId)
{
string link = "";
if (Request.QueryString["mode"] != null)
{
    link = "~/CustDetails.aspx?id="+CustId;
}
else
{

}
return link;
}
```

And here's my "HTML"

```asp
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
<ItemTemplate>
<a href='<%# Response.Write(getLink(Eval(Container.DataItem,"CustId")))%>'>
<li><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Name")%></li>
```

Comment: What is the problem? Do you get any errors? What are you trying to achieve? I don't think you need to add data item, just use simple `Eval("CustId")`.

Comment: The problem is that I wanna put the value from "CustId" to my Function. It gives error :  CS1502.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get `The best overloaded method match for '' has some invalid arguments` error because your function takes `string` as parameter, and you give it the `object` - the `Eval()` function returns an `object`. You can either use

```
protected String getLink(object CustId)
```

and convert it to string later, or the better way:

```
Response.Write(getLink(Eval(Container.DataItem,"CustId").ToString()))
```

That way you can keep your function unchanged.

Comment: Glad it helped ;) Just out of curiosity - can you try simple `Eval("CustId").ToString()` and tell if it works?

Answer (score 0):

You should use linkbutton inside repeater with

```
<asp:LinkButton ID ="asd" runat ="server" Text ='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Name")%>' CommandArgument ='<%# Eval(Container.DataItem,"CustId")%>'></asp:LinkButton>
```

And set the OnItemCommand Property of repeater to call an event like this;

```
Response.Redirect("~/CustDetails.aspx?id="+Convert.toInt32(e.commandArgument));
```

Comment: Some people preffer to use pure html, and not asp controls. One of the reasons is that asp control is run at server, and it's sometimes important to use it on client side ;)

Comment: Sorry, not that I was looking for.

Comment: He's already using an asp control "repeater" and calling a function on .cs server side. Thought it was appropriate.